# Cannot export to a named Excel range using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, export, export-to-excel

I am developing a SSIS package which is retrieving data from database and exporting it into a pre-formatted Excel file. This is not the first time I am doing this, but this time it won't work and I can't find out why..

[image]

As you can see in attached image, SSIS exports data successfully but writes it in the bad cells, I specified the value "operateur$B14:F19" in the OpenRowset property of Excel destination in SSIS though..

In addition, I am getting an error which is saying:

> Cannot Expand Named Range

How can I fix this?

Comment: have you find any solution ...

Comment: @sandeeprawat Yes, it's awkward but it worked. I changed the range value to "operateur$B9:F14" and it wrote the data into "operateur$B14:F19" !

Answer (score 0):

SSIS is not right tool set to solve this type of scenario. Use SSRS.

But any way you can try below steps.

Populate required data in table and use [micro](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CjBEguRTkII) or [data connection](http://dascomputerconsultants.com/EmbedSQLInExcel.htm) to populate excel...

Comment: You can generate report using SSRS  and calling them in ssis ...   go throw https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3475/execute-a-sql-server-reporting-services-report-from-integration-services-package/